# C# Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<AnonymousType#1>'

Tags: c#, linq, datatable

> Cannot implicitly convert type `'System.Collections.Generic.List<AnonymousType#1>'` to `'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<System.Data.DataRow>'`. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

I have two datatable called Data2,Data3,
I want to  input data into Data3 after group by.
How do I modify my Code?

```
IEnumerable<DataRow> temp = (from p in Data2.AsEnumerable()
                              group p by new
                              {
                                  ID = p.Field<string>("ID"),
                                  StyleID = p.Field<string>("StyleID"),
                                  BrandID = p.Field<string>("BrandID"),
                                  SeasonID = p.Field<string>("SeasonID"),
                                  Article = p.Field<string>("Article"),
                                  PatternCode = p.Field<string>("PatternCode")
                              } into g
                              select new
                              {
                                  ID = g.Key.ID,
                                  StyleID = g.Key.StyleID,
                                  BrandID = g.Key.BrandID,
                                  SeasonID = g.Key.SeasonID,
                                  Article = g.Key.Article,
                                  PatternCode = g.Key.PatternCode,
                                  QTY = g.Sum(p => p.Field<int>("QTY"))
                              }).ToList();

                 Data3 = temp.CopyToDataTable();
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The projection:

```
  select new
  {
      ID = g.Key.ID,
      StyleID = g.Key.StyleID,
      BrandID = g.Key.BrandID,
      SeasonID = g.Key.SeasonID,
      Article = g.Key.Article,
      PatternCode = g.Key.PatternCode,
      QTY = g.Sum(p => p.Field<int>("QTY"))
  }
```

means you are creating per row, an instance of an *anonymous type* (a class generated by the compiler); *not* a `DataRow`. So when you `.ToList()` that, you get a `List<T>` where `T` is the anonymous type. You can do `var temp  = ...` to *assign* the list to something, but it still won't be anything to do with `DataRow`. You'll need to (one of):

- not use `DataTable`/`DataRow` (seriously, they're awful; just about anything else is preferable)
- populate a `DataTable` manually by looping over your objects, creating rows and assigning values
- use a tool that automates the above point

Answer (score 1):

try this :

```
      var temp = (from p in Data2.AsEnumerable()
                          group p by new
                          {
                              ID = p.Field<string>("ID"),
                              StyleID = p.Field<string>("StyleID"),
                              BrandID = p.Field<string>("BrandID"),
                              SeasonID = p.Field<string>("SeasonID"),
                              Article = p.Field<string>("Article"),
                              PatternCode = p.Field<string>("PatternCode")
                          } into g
                          select new
                          {
                              ID = g.Key.ID,
                              StyleID = g.Key.StyleID,
                              BrandID = g.Key.BrandID,
                              SeasonID = g.Key.SeasonID,
                              Article = g.Key.Article,
                              PatternCode = g.Key.PatternCode,
                              QTY = g.Sum(p => p.Field<int>("QTY"))
                          }).ToList();
 Data3 =ConvertToDataTable(temp);


 public DataTable ConvertToDataTable<T>(IList<T> data)
    {
        PropertyDescriptorCollection properties =
            TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(typeof(T));

        DataTable table = new DataTable();

        foreach (PropertyDescriptor prop in properties)
            table.Columns.Add(prop.Name, Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(prop.PropertyType) ?? prop.PropertyType);

        foreach (T item in data)
        {
            DataRow row = table.NewRow();
            foreach (PropertyDescriptor prop in properties)
                row[prop.Name] = prop.GetValue(item) ?? DBNull.Value;
            table.Rows.Add(row);
        }
        return table;
    }
```